# EasyAdmin 3 Dashbord Crud::PAGE_INDEX with delete Button only for deletable entitys

Tags: entity, symfony5, easyadmin

I search for a solution to create in an **EasyAdmin 3** Backend  on the INDEX View.  So That allowed me only add a delete button to delatable items.  Thanks for help

```
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        $deleteSite = Action::new('drop', 'Delete', 'fas fa-delete')
            ->displayIf(
                static function ($entity) {
                    return $entity->getIsDeletable();
                }
            )->linkToCrudAction(Crud::PAGE_INDEX);

        return $actions
            ->remove(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, 'delete')
            ->remove(Crud::PAGE_DETAIL, 'delete')
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, 'detail')
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $deleteSite)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_DETAIL, $deleteSite);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this with a custom controller

```
public function index(): Response
    {
      $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $messages = $entityManager->getRepository(MessageUpdate::class)->getLastMessage();
      return $this->render('/front/dashboard.html.twig', [
        'messages' => $messages
]);
```

Then in the twig file :

```
  {% for message in messages %}
  <br>
    <p>Modification le {{message.datePublished|date('d-m-Y')}} {{ message.title }} {{ message.message }} </p> .

    <form action="/admin/deleteMessage/{{message.id}}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="supprimer"
         name="Submit" id="frm1_submit" />
    </form>

    <br>
  {% endfor %}
```

And in the controller :

```
/**
   * @Route("admin/deleteMessage/{id}", name="messageUpdate_delete" , methods={"POST"})
   */
  public function deleteMessage($id){

     $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MessageUpdate::class);
     $message = $repository->find($id);
     $repository->deleteMessage($id);

     $messages = $repository->getLastMessage();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
```

Maybe not the best way to do it, but it work ;)